# Calculate $P(H>2N)$ using the joint density function $f_{NH}(n,h)=0.1e^{-0.5n-0.2h}$

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

I need to calculate $P(H>2N)$ using the joint density function $f_{NH}(n,h)=0.1e^{-0.5n-0.2h}$. $N$ and $H$ are both continuous random variables that follow an exponential distribution with $\lambda=0.5$ and $\lambda=0.2$ respectively. I know that I need to use double integrals but I am unsure as to what values I should be integrating between.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First note that the region is described by $0 < 2n < h < \infty$. If you integrate with respect to $h$ first, then we have $2n < h < \infty$ as you inner integral limits, and after integrating out $h$ you just integrate $n$ from $0$ to $\infty$, i.e. the entire support. If you integrate with respect to $n$ first, then you now consider $0 < n < h/2$ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, instead of the usual $x$-$y$ axis, change it to the $n$-$h$ axis (arbitrarily). Recall that the $N$ and $H$ are defined on $n, h \geq 0$. Now draw the line $h = 2n$ and notice that we are interested in $h>2n$, which is the region above the line. If we choose to integrate along $h$ first, then we are calculating
$$P(H>2N) = \int_0^\infty\int_{2n}^\infty f_{N,H}(n,h) \,dhdn.$$

Alternatively, you might have learned that $kX\sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda/k)$ and $P(X>Y) = \frac{\mu}{\mu+\lambda}$ when $X\sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim \operatorname{Exp}(\mu)$. Then notice that $2N\sim \operatorname{Exp}(1/4)$ and so $$P(H>2N) = \frac{1/4}{1/5+1/4} = \frac{5}{9}.$$